# Python threading.Thread : random occurrences of missing final newline of print()

Tags: python, multithreading

I am just in a process of learning how to use the Python threading module and come up with following code which should help me to understand how threading works:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
closeAllThreads = False
threadCounter = 0
def runMeAsThread():
    global closeAllThreads, threadCounter
    threadCounter += 1
    sleepValue = threadCounter
    while not closeAllThreads:
        print(f'runMeAsThread(): {threadCounter = } {sleepValue = }', flush=True)
        sleep(sleepValue)
firstThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread)
firstThreadObj.start()
secondThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread)
secondThreadObj.start()
thirdThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread)
thirdThreadObj.start()
sleep(5)
closeAllThreads = True
```

**What is wrong with my expectation that all of the printed lines should be printed in a separate line?**

I am getting randomly occuring cases where two lines are printed on one line like:

```
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 1 sleepValue = 1
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 2 sleepValue = 2
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 3
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 1
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 2runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 1

runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 3runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 1

runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 2
runMeAsThread(): threadCounter = 3 sleepValue = 1
```

I have already included the , flush=True print option to get rid of this behavior, but it didn' help. How does it come? Could it happen that also the line contents get 'mixed'?

Comment: the built in print function is not thread safe.

Comment: @Alexander : what does it mean "print() is not thread safe'? How to know which functions are and which are not? What could I use instead of print() to write to the apparently by all the threads shared same stdout without mixing the content of output? Would it be necessary to inform the other threads if printing to wait until print() is finished by a kind of Lock() ?

Comment: You are accessing a shared resource - the standard output stream - with no synchronization.

Comment: I have searched the Internet for an answer to my question, but was not able to find out that it is already answered here on stackoverflow. Consider this statement as hint towards improving the search function here on stackoverflow in order to make it able to come up with actual duplicates already while writing a question. This would save much work preventing duplicate questions to be asked and the effort of closing the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in print function is not thread safe, which basically means you risk corrupting the printed messages if you use it in multiple threads simultaneously.

What you can do to prevent this is either use a mutex or a queue.  Below are examples on how to use both.

Typically if a function is thread safe it will be documented as such, it's probably best to assume that a function or method is not thread safe unless it explicitly states that it is.

For the queue example:

```
import queue
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

closeAllThreads = False
threadCounter = 0

def printingThread(my_queue):
    while not closeAllThreads:
        try:
            msg = my_queue.get(timeout=1)
            print(msg)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

def runMeAsThread(my_queue):
    global closeAllThreads, threadCounter
    threadCounter += 1
    sleepValue = threadCounter
    while not closeAllThreads:
        my_queue.put(f'runMeAsThread(): {threadCounter = } {sleepValue = }')
        sleep(sleepValue)


my_queue = queue.Queue()
firstThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(my_queue,))
firstThreadObj.start()

secondThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(my_queue,))
secondThreadObj.start()

thirdThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(my_queue,))
thirdThreadObj.start()

fourthThreadObj = Thread(None, printingThread, args=(my_queue,))
fourthThreadObj.start()

sleep(5)
closeAllThreads = True
```

Or you can use a lock object:

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
from threading import Lock


closeAllThreads = False
threadCounter = 0
def runMeAsThread(lock):
    global closeAllThreads, threadCounter
    threadCounter += 1
    sleepValue = threadCounter
    while not closeAllThreads:
        with lock:  # only print while the thread has acquired the lock
            print(f'runMeAsThread(): {threadCounter = } {sleepValue = }')
        sleep(sleepValue)


lock = Lock()  #  all threads share the same lock object
firstThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(lock,))
firstThreadObj.start()

secondThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(lock,))
secondThreadObj.start()

thirdThreadObj = Thread(None,runMeAsThread, args=(lock,))
thirdThreadObj.start()

sleep(5)
closeAllThreads = True
```

Comment: Yes there are literally innumerable number of ways to implement using a queue or a mutex.  My example is simply to demonstrate how they work.  you could even get away with not even using the 4th thread function I created and just pull the messages from the queue in the same thread.  You should read the documentation to get a better understanding of their possibilities.  @Claudio

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean about the "\n" part...  Where do you see that?  EDIT, I see what you are saying... yes... you can add a timeout to the get function so that it doesn't stay frozen when you are trying to exit.... I will update the example to show that.

Comment: I already updated it.... and like I said before this was only a demonstration.

Comment: Oh... that is because the variable is overwriting the module name.... you just need to change it to something else.  I will edit it.

Comment: That works too... or you can see the edited example...